# [C#][AutoMapper] How many maps should I create?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper in my .NET Core MVC Domain-Driven project. I have a question about an amount of created maps. I will give You an example:

```
            CreateMap<Contact, ContactDto>();
            CreateMap<ContactDto, Contact>();

            CreateMap<Contact, AddContactCommand>();
            CreateMap<AddContactCommand, Contact>();

            CreateMap<Contact, EditContactCommand>();
            CreateMap<EditContactCommand, Contact>();
```

Would it be possible to map a **ContactDto** object to for example a **EditContactCommad** object? Or maybe I should create a direct map?

Comment: You have to create a map between those types. And you can also use `ReverseMap` method to make a map in reverse order:  CreateMap<Contact, ContactDto>().ReverseMap();`

Answer (score 0):

You can create all the maps you need :) But be sure to separate them logically using profiles. Once you have more than a few hundred, performance might suffer. Then you might need further separation using different configuration instances that you can initialize in parallel. But hopefully that's a problem for the future. In 11.0, configuration performance will be better, so you should upgrade then.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean if having above mappings AutoMapper will automatically map ContactDto to EditContactCommand? I would say no. ContactDto may only have subset of Contact properties.

For example simplified version:

```
public class Contact 
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EditContactCommad 
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ContactDto would lack information for EditContactCommad. In general transformations may be applied. So you must create direct one.